# create-react-app node-less compilation

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using `node-less` compiler with my `create-react-app` webpack config in order to compile my less files. The compilation is EXTREMELY slow and takes nearly 5-8 secs for every file change.

Here's a part of my webpack config that specifies less compilation:

```
{
  exclude: [
    /\.html$/,
    /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    /\.css$/,
    /\.json$/,
    /\.svg$/,
    /\.less$/
  ],
  loader: 'url',
  query: {
    limit: 10000,
    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
  }
},

{
  test: /\.less$/,
  loaders: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName="[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"',
    'postcss-loader',
    'less-loader'
  ]
},
```

I want the compilation to be as fast (or nearly as fast) as before (when I didn't user the less loader)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I also started with the less loader but then read Dan Abramov's comment on adding css pre-prossesor and switched to his solution. Works really great - below is a link to the comment, but in short - you don't need to eject and change create-react-app default configuration - just add a file watcher that monitors and compiles your less files into css files and let webpack use these compiled css files. No changes to config required!

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc.